# incorporating prefix into binary search algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search, prefix

As part of a homework assignment, I'm told to incorporate the use of prefixes into the standard binary search algorithm, i.e,

```
int binarySearch( AnyType[] a, AnyType x, AnyType prefix )
{
    int low = 0; high = a.length - 1;

    while( low <= high )
    {
        int mid = ( low + high ) / 2; 

            #what goes here????

        if( a[ mid ].compareTo( x ) < 0 )
        {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
        else if( a[ mid ].compareTo( x ) > 0 )
        {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return mid;
        }
    }

    return NOT_FOUND;
}
```

I'm told that the change is simple, and asked which version is faster. I'm having trouble understanding how to incorporate prefixes into the algorithm.

The context is that I was incorporating prefixes into a hash function program, where for each word in a hash, I knew that the prefix to that word was also stored in the hash. That way, I could cut down on my calculations by checking to see if the prefix was in the table before going on with the rest of the word. ( it was a word search program )

EDIT: Here is what I'm looking at currently. Any ideas on the performance of this one?

```
int binarySearch( AnyType[] a, AnyType x, AnyType prefix )
{
    int low = 0; high = a.length - 1;

    while( low <= high )
    {
        int mid = ( low + high ) / 2;

        if( a[ mid ].compareTo( prefix ) < 0 )
        {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
        else if( a[ mid ].compareTo( prefix ) > 0 )
        {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            high = mid;
            while( low <= high )
            {
                int mid = ( low + high ) / 2;

                if( a[ mid ].compareTo( x ) < 0 )
                {
                    low = mid + 1;
                }
                else if( a[ mid ].compareTo( x ) > 0 )
                {
                    high = mid - 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    return mid;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return NOT_FOUND;
}
```

Comment: You have a search element **and** a prefix? What are you even supposed to do with that (logically, not in code ... and in detail)? With regard to which is faster, look at the code for `compareTo` (and whatever other function you choose to use for prefixes), which should be easy enough to get (assuming this is Java), to figure out how it works, which should make telling which is faster easy enough. Also, calling `compareTo` twice is inefficient - just store the result in a variable.

Comment: I think it's about the general algorithm.

And in the original program, the idea was that you take a list of words and hash them. But wait, you also hash their prefixes. Later, when searching for a word, (one character at a time because it's a word search), you can check before you're done building the word to see if the prefix is in the hash. If it isn't, you've just cut out a bunch more work. Since many of the words will have the same prefix, theoretically the hash table won't be much bigger.

Comment: And I'm not sure how, but I'm supposed to translate that kind of thinking into a simple binary search algorithm

Comment: You wouldn't need to actually insert the prefixes, just use `String.substring` somewhere in there. "That kind of thinking" would be 2 **completely separate** searches, although they might also want you to just put the prefix check inside the existing loop (similar to the if-else-if-else you currently have, just with checking up to the prefix using `substring`, then `compareTo`), but doing either of these will just make the method take longer, so I have no idea what this is supposed to teach you.

Comment: What would I do after checking for prefix? set that location to mid?
That's what I'm confused about: how does using prefix improve the algorithm?

Comment: I see no possible way in which checking for the prefix improves the algorithm, which is rather my point. If the prefix matches, just continue with the `compareTo` check you currently have. If it doesn't match, set either `low` or `high` in a way similar to the way you currently do.

Comment: is it okay for me to quote the actual question?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50829/discussion-between-thephfactor-and-dukeling)

Comment: @thephfactor What is the prefix like, can you add an example of an input in your post.

Comment: I was not given an example input. I'm assuming it is just a substring of a String word, since the context was a word search.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a way of storing prefixes in a array in such a way that binary search is applicable. There is a basic requirement for an array inorder for binary search can be applied. Think on those lines. :)

Comment: For a binary search though, would I have to actually store the prefixes as separate elements in an array?

Comment: Yes. then binary search can be applied.

Comment: Also intead of storing prefixes maybe just the indices of prefixes from the array can be stored. This is a little tricky though

Comment: But as far as the actual algorithm, do you have any wisdom on how that would play out logically? Am I close with the edit above?

Comment: Sorry I didn't read the above comments before. Maybe suffix arrays is what you are looking for http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/suffix-array-set-1-introduction/